# file in/out error with CUDA 5.0

Tags: debugging, file-io, cuda

After downloading the latest toolkit and compiling/running the code that I currently have, I get a debug assertion error with any sort of file IO functions. Even the code below will exit with an assertion error when fprintf is called.

```
//main.cu

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( void ) {
    FILE* foo;
    foo=fopen("C:\\asdfsa.txt","w");
    fprintf(foo,"wtf\n");
    fclose(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using CUDA toolkit 5.0, and Visual studio.
Any idea on what is going on? My code worked fine on my older computer with an old version cuda toolkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the fopen return value. Looks like you are running the code on the entirely new environmnent - maybe you can't create the file in the C:\ (e.g. this may require admin permissions)